# what does @ mean in inline assembly?

Tags: inline-assembly

```
__asm__ __volatile__
  ("@ call(start) \n\t"
   "mov     lr, pc       \n\t"
   "@ call(end)   \n\t"
   :
```

It looks like defining a region for function call, but could you explain more?

Comment: Also specify compiler ..

Comment: That's GCC inline assembly syntax, and `mov lr,pc` smells ARMish to me, but I'm not going to speculate further until that's confirmed, and we also need to know what OS and the exact toolchain identity.  I'd also like to see the whole function.

Answer (score 0):

Making an educated guess that you're using GCC to target ARM, `@` starts a comment that extends to the end of that line. See [GNU AS Manual - ARM Syntax - Special Characters](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/ARM_002dChars.html#ARM_002dChars).